# GAE + Django. app-engine-patch or django-gae-helpers?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm building app using GAE and wanted to use Django for that. Which "patch" is better? app-engine-patch or django-gae-helpers? I mean functionality and future of them (will one of them die soon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by django-gae-helpers you refer to http://code.google.com/p/django-gae-helpers/ then there's nothing you can use there yet.

I haven't tried app-engine-patch but I've used goole-app-engine-django. It took a bit of trial and error to get it working but it works quite well (I miss the admin though).

I would give app-engine-patch a try, they say there're better than google-app-engine-django and include the admin and more...

Comment: I actually just downloaded app-engine-patch and was able to get it running very quickly and to upload it to gae. I haven't tried any of the features yet.

Comment: I have running app-engine-patch and it looks nice. Just wanted to know, if i'm going right way ;) Don't want to end with lots of code and have to rewrite it to other "patch" ;) But i see that it was good choice.

Comment: Took me few minutes to get up and running with patch. very straigtforward.

Answer (score 3):

app-engine-patch gives you the latest stable django and except database models (you have to use google datastore) is pretty much compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Found this question when searching for something that compared http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/ vs. http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/ .   Anyone have experience with both of those?

Comment: found a question addressing that specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237516/should-i-use-google-app-engine-django-or-app-engine-patch-or-neither-or-something