# Should I use google-app-engine-django or app-engine-patch or neither or something else?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Do I need either to make Django easier to use on GAE? Anyone had good or bad experience of either or any equivalent? Is there much difference between these? Which is easier to use?

Regards

Geoff

Answer (score 11):

I am assuming you want to run django on app engine (otherwise using appengine API directly is the best solution).

Altho' Google App engine supports django 1.0 out of the box, django admin, auth doesn't work on it, as they are dependent on the models.

Appengine patch patches django to make the admin work even on the Bigtable API.

Appengine patch also often makes sure to work on the latest release of django.

So, again, "You should use App engine patch"

Comment: According to the app engine patch site, "app-engine-patch is no longer being updated " and "Join the Django nonrel project and follow the Django nonrel blog (which is written with Django nonrel) if you want to use Django's ORM on App Engine and other NoSQL / non-relational databases. Django nonrel will allow to run your code on App Engine, MongoDB, SimpleDB, and SQL without any modifications..."

Comment: btol45, Thanks. It is True. However this was answered in Aug 2009, which is like 8 months ago :)

Answer (score 4):

Google App Engine Patch seems to have died sometime around August 2009.

http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/issues/detail?id=253

Comment: It supports Django 1.1 and the replacement (http://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/django-nonrel/) is not ready yet, so it is still a good option.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what exactly you want to develop.

You should use *app-engine-patch* if you need the [**Django Admin interface**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#ref-contrib-admin), otherwise *google-app-engine-django* should be enough.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I will try app-engine-patch

Answer (score 0):

Use Django patch if you already have django application that you know that you want to use. Remember that GAE comes with its own API/applications.