# app-engine-patch is dead. Now what is the best way to use Django on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, app-engine-patch

The app-engine-patch authors have officially marked this wonderful project as dead  [on their website.](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/) Over the last year a lot of people have asked what the best way to run Django on Google App Engine was, and time after time people have pointed to app-engine-patch being the way to go. Now that this project is dead, I would love to revisit this discussion and see what you all would recommend.

The old app-engine-patch website refers to a different project called [djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine) that they are working on. It focuses on using Native Django on App Engine but by doing so appears to limit your ability to use all of App Engine's features (such as its built in User model). What do you all think about this as a replacement solution?

Does the [Google App Engine Helper For Django](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/appengine_helper_for_django.html) project now look more inviting now that app-engine-patch has died?

Or is app-engine-patch still so great that you would recommend still using it despite it being dead?

I currently have a project in its middle stages relying on app-engine-patch and have loved using it so far, but am scared to continue using a project that is dead. I would really appreciate any comments you have about what you think the best long term solution is now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App engine patch is probably a safer bet for a given moment. Though not actively supported at the moment, it's still great, as it's been tested more thoroughly. If you're ready to take some risks - go and give the new djangoappengine+django-nonrel (native django support for non relational databases, primarily google datastore yest) option a try. That is the option we'll all use in a little while, so probably it's worth to try it out and not to look back. For instance, app engine patch only supports ~300 entities in the admin (i.e. doesn't take advantage of the 1.3.1 functionality), while with the djangoappengine+django-nonrel that is not an issues anymore. www.allbuttonspressed.com, a site of the guys behind app-engine-patch, is all built this new way, you can grab the source code of the site's skeleton @ http://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/allbuttonspressed/.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have looked into their project a lot closer over the past day and it does seem to have a lot of promise. I believe I will attempt to migrate over to djangoappengine + django-nonrel in the very near future.

Comment: Always welcome ;) Good luck trying out djangoappengine + django-nonrel, please let me know how it worked out, as i'm planning to try it as well, just a bit too busy coping with other stuff at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can just import it using use_library...

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html

Comment: Yes, this is an option but doesn't seem as appealing as any of the others for the reasons mentioned in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029511/django-google-app-engine-app-engine-helper-for-django-or-use-library